# problems with urllib2 when requesting twitter api

Tags: python, twitter, urllib2

I'm using the twitter api wrapper to make some calls but I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tweets.py", line 100, in <module>
    print stream_country('marketing','fr') + stream_worldwide('marketing') + stream_country('marketing','it') +  stream_country('marketing','en')
  File "tweets.py", line 41, in stream_country
    search = t.search.tweets(q = keyword, lang = 'fr', count = 100, since_id = max_ID)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twitter/api.py", line 204, in __call__
    return self._handle_response(req, uri, arg_data, _timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twitter/api.py", line 211, in _handle_response
    handle = urllib_request.urlopen(req, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1177, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution>
```

Code:

```
from twitter import *
t = Twitter(
    auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET,
               CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
)
since_ID = -1
max_ID = 0
tcount = 0
while(since_ID != max_ID):
    search = t.search.tweets(q = keyword, lang = 'fr', count = 100, since_id = max_ID)

    #print len(search['statuses'])
    if len(search['statuses']) == 0:
        #print 'end'
        break

    since_ID = search['search_metadata']['since_id_str']
    max_ID = search['search_metadata']['max_id_str']

    for doc in search['statuses']:
        #print doc['text']
        tcount += 1

return tcount
```

Comment: Code please. We'd like to check ourselves.

Comment: What is `t`? There seems to be no variable instantiated.

Comment: sorry i didn't put the authentication part of the code

Comment: Seems pretty clear, it's unable to look up a hostname for the URL. You can either turn on urllib debugging OR use a proxy like mitmproxy to funnel all your calls through a nice UI that shows you the outgoing requests. You might want to get used to using mitmproxy as pretty much any web crawling / automation you do will benefit greatly by having a standard environment for you to drill down into whats actually going on.

Comment: @synthesizerpatel i probably have no connection to the web. i use a linux VM to make this call. in the linux VM, i realised the ping google.com gives unknown hostname aswell. so just to get access to web might resolve this??